# Oracle SQL Count grouped rows in table

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count

I was wonder if it is possible preferably using a select statement on PL/SQL V11 to get the following results from this table:

```
Area    Store   Product
10      1       A
10      1       B
11      1       E
11      1       D
10      2       C
10      2       B
10      2       A
10      3       B
10      3       A
13      1       B
13      1       A
```

and Return this result, so it groups by Area, and Store and looks for and area and store with the same products. So Area 10 Store 1 has products A and B so it will look at the list for other stores that only have A and B and count them. In this example it counts Area 10 store 1/Area 10 store 3/Area 13 Store 1.

```
Product Count of groups
AB      3
ABC     1
DE      1
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `listagg()` and then another `group by`:

```
select products, count(*)
from (select listagg(product) within group (order by product) as products
      from t
      group by area, store
     ) p
group by products;
```